# How can I determine how many bytes an I2C master read from my Arduino acting as I2C slave?

Tags: i2c, atmega328, wire-library

I have an Atmega328 programmed using the Arduino software and libraries (but is standalone on on a board in the TSOP package) without bootloader and with ISP programming). I am using the Wire library to act as an I2C peripheral, where I implement (and register) the `requestEvent` and `receiveEvent` callbacks.

Is it possible to determine, either during the `requestEvent` callback or after it at some point, how many bytes were read by the master before it sent a NACK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The master will have to inform the slave how many bytes to transfer, or the master will have to query the slave how many bytes there are to receive.

Comment: I understand that the protocol doesn't specify that. I'm interested in getting the number of bytes that were actually sent by the slave until the master sent a NACK instead of an ACK, as I specified originally in the question (be it through another callback, by calling a Wire function, etc), after the send actually completes.

Comment: *actually completes at the physical level, after the master sends the NACK.

Comment: You have no access to that level of information through the API. You can count how many times your callback is called, but that's as close as you get. You would have to work out some way of knowing what is the first transfer though.

Comment: You would have to work entirely at the register level and implement your own I2C code.

Comment: OK, that clarification answers the question perfectly.